# i want my heading to span across width of page

Tags: html, css

I have the following heading "2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention".
I have it in an `h1` tag in my coding. I want it to spread out across the webpage so that it starts on the left and ends on the right (a little padding wouldn't hurt).

I tried doing this by increasing the font but the height becomes too large. I just want it to be around 2 inches in height. I tried span and center tags but they weren't what i was looking for either. Also, I want the text in small caps. Spacing between the letters don't matter as long as it isn't too much.
Any help is greatly appreciated

EDIT: the code didn't show when i first posted. i realized later i did it wrong. Thanks for the down votes though -.- Here's the code:

```css
.heading {
  font: 55px;
}
```

```html
<body class="main">

  <h1><span>2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</span></h1>

  <div class="heading"><center>2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</center></div>

</body>
```

I tried this later

```css
#heading {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="heading">2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</div>
```

Comment: share the code you have so we can help you

Comment: if you're confused at the h1 and div-heading tags in the same coding, i didn't write it together in the real file. I tried them separately but just included both here to show that i used both variations of code but it didn't work

Comment: so you want the text of the h1 to spread across the whole width or you want the tag <h1> or `.heading` to be width:100% ? you question is unclear

Comment: ohh... i see. I want the text to be 100% width of the page.

Comment: don't really need to use js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try style .letter-spacing

```
<h1 style="letter-spacing: 10px;">2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</h1>
```

Increase letter spacing distance as per requirement.

Comment: thanks a bunch. this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It would be worthwhile if you posted some code to show us what you have done. But use this below as a starting point if you wish.

```
<div id="heading">2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</div>

#heading {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the width of the div was 100% but the text stayed small. Is there anyway to fix that? I want to widen the text as well.

Comment: Try `text-align: justify;`. That will make the text like that in a newspaper. You can then play around with the font size.

Comment: this one didn't exactly work, but it came close. The justify alignment didn't work for some reason though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   .wrapper {
          margin:0 auto;
          width:960px;
          max-width:100%;
    }

    .heading {
          width:100%;
          margin:0;
          padding:40px 0;
    }

    .heading h1 {
          font-size:35pt;
          font-family:tahoma;
          color:black;
          text-align:center;
          line-height:35pt;
    }

<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="heading">
          <h1>This is my website</h1>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Start using jsfiddle.net

```css
.heading {
  font: 55px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</h1>

<div class="heading">
  <center>2015 Annual Architectural Design Convention</center>
</div>
```